# Number of simple paths on a square grid

Tags: combinatorics

Given $L\times L$ square grid and two points $a=(x_a,y_a)$ and $b=(x_b,y,_b)$, how many simple paths are there from $a$ to $b$? With simple I mean no point is visited twice and the path can only one step north, south, east and west each time. I assume that this number is not exactly computable, so I am also interested in some partial questions to this problem:

1. How to approximate this number and how good is the approximation?
2. What are the lower/upper bounds on the total number of paths and how good are these bounds?
3. What can we say about the number of paths with a given length $l$ (a path of length $l$ has traversed $l$ edges)? Approximations or bounds on this number are also apreciated.

For all intents and purposes, you may assume that $a$ and $b$ lie in the bulk of the grid and that the size of the grid is large enough such that boundary effects can be neglected.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk